# Multiple from clauses in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

How can this LINQ query expression be re-expressed with extension method calls?

```
public static List<Tuple<int, int>> Concat()
{
    return (from x in Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
           from y in Enumerable.Range(4, 3)
           select new Tuple<int, int>(x, y)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: _Any_ LINQ query can be expressed with extension method calls. This is by definition - all LINQ keywords are defined in the language spec by providing expansion to corresponding method calls.

Comment: Could have checked out with Reflector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 3).SelectMany(
    i => Enumerable.Range(4, 3),
    (i, j) => new Tuple<int, int>(i, j)
).ToList();
```

Comment: Using the overloaded SelectMany with a resultSelector function seams more readable to me. Given that this is a translation of my Haskell list comprehension [(x,y)|x<-[1,2,3],y<-[4,5,6]].

Comment: This example of can be written more concisely using the point-free style.(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-free_programming)

Enumerable.Range(1, 3).SelectMany(
    i => Enumerable.Range(4, 3), 
    Tuple.Create
).ToList();

Answer (score 10):

```
return Enumerable.Range(1, 3).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(4, 3)
           .Select(y => new Tuple<int, int>(x, y))).ToList();
```

Your version looks more readable :-)